# Configuring HAProxy+nginx+PHP-FPM to out perform Apache+mod_php

Tags: apache, nginx, haproxy, php

**Edit**

Running my OS on the VirtualBox was the issue. As soon as I made my OS the native on the disk, I was able to see the performance boost.

**Original**

I've read a lot of people recommend ditching Apache+mod_php for HAProxy+nginx+PHP-FPM. I'm trying to verify that it's a more efficient setup, but am not seeing the results people describe. Both siege and ab (Apache Benchmark) are showing that Apache at any number of concurrent connections is giving better responses per second, and can support more connections .

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 server on VirtualBox. It has 10 gigs of space, and 1,344 megs of memory. I used apt-get for installing the programs mentioned above. Here are the related config files with just the important parts included.

haproxy.cfg

```
global
        maxconn 4096
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon
        stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock mode 0600 level admin

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        option  redispatch
        maxconn 2000
        contimeout      5000
        clitimeout      50000
        srvtimeout      50000

listen tcpcluster *:80
        mode tcp
        option tcplog
        balance roundrobin

        server tcp01 192.168.1.199:8080 check
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 2;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}
```

www.conf

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 4
pm.max_requests = 500
```

apache.conf

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients           10
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients           10
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients           10
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Given that PHP-FPM and Apache both have a maximum of 10 children, I would expect that any speed advantage would be visible. In every test I've run (always waiting until load is 0.01 before I run the test), Apache is always able to handle more request more efficiently.

Is there some other optimization that can be made so that the setup best suited to scale will outperform the setup that should not be more efficient?

Comment: Increase the load to 3.00, 6.00 and finally 10.00. Then compare how the boxes behave. A load of 0.01 is not saying much at all.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear on that part. I wait until the load average goes down to 0.01 before I run another test. The load after each test could get up to 15 or 20, and I wanted to give each a level playing field to start off with.

Comment: The primary issue was using Virtual Box to house the OS. As soon as I installed it as a native OS, the timing advantages of this setup became apparent.

Comment: Please leave your solution as an answer below (not as an edit of your question). After some moments in time you can accept it and this will mark your question as solved. This would be helpful for future users because it is much more clear that this question has an (accepted) answer. Please do so, this is very much accepted here on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Use haproxy as a connection concentrator : use "mode http" instead of "mode tcp", use "option http-server-close" and set a server maxconn value well below the worker connections value. You should cross a point where the lower concurrency brings much more performance with much lower RAM usage and better cache efficiency along the whole chain.

BTW, what are the numbers we're talking about ? Do they measure in hundreds or in thousands of requests per second ? Because clearly, the application server will make a real difference only in the higher loads. Obviously if the application runs very slowly, there is no reason to see a difference when replacing the server.

Comment: Is tcp mode more efficient than http? I always thought load balancing on a lower layer would be more efficient.

I'll give those suggestions a shot. Now that I think about it, I was running siege and ab with a low amount of requests per connection compared to a high total number of connections.

Comment: No, it's the opposite, HTTP mode is more efficient than TCP. Some people find it surprizing first, but when you consider that in HTTP you know on which side data are expected, you understand that it reduces polling. Anyway, we're speaking about differences that can be observed only at tens of thousands of connections per second. Also, in HTTP it's possible to immediately close idle connections, which is not possible in TCP since you don't know they're idle.